# Offscreen UIView responding to taps

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a root view controller with two child view controllers, call them X and Y, both of which are instances of the same subclass of UIViewController. (So their appearance and functionality are identical.) X was added to the root view controller first, then we will add Y. X.view's frame is the entire screen area, and Y.view's frame will be offset to the right by one screen-width (so it is completely off-screen) when Y is instantiated.

When the user presses a button, Y is instantiated and added to the root view controller, then both X and Y slide simultaneously one screen-width to the left, so that X.view's frame exits stage left and Y.view's enters from stage right. The animation that does this has a delay.

I've found that if I click the button on X that causes the instantiation of Y and triggers this animation, and then click another button on X during the animation delay, the button click isn't passed to the button on X but instead to the analogous button on Y, so that it comes over already pressed.

Why is this happening and what is the fix?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**YOU SHOULD SPECIFY WHICH VIEW TO KEEP IN FRONT AND WHICH TO BACKGROUND-:**

```
IF X YOU WANT TO BECOME ACTIVE THEN- 
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:X.view]

IF Y YOU WANT TO BECOME INACTIVE THEN- 
[Y.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

OR
Try something like:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:yourSubview]
```

or

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow bringSubviewToFront:yourSubview]
```

Comment: I ended up using the setUserInteractionEnabled: method to fix the issue. Ah, what a simple fix! I don't quite understand how changing subview ordering would fix anything since the views have no overlap at all. It seems to me like somehow, when the animation is called, the iOS considers all the controls to have already been moved onscreen and treats touch events as such, it just hasn't finished animating the display. Or something. Anyways, I'll remember to set the user interaction enabled property before and after the animation. Thanks!